# Show max variable price in shop page

Tags: variables, woocommerce

I want to display the maximum variation price in woocommerce shop page under product title.

I have tried using this code but does not seem to work, only breaks my site instead.

add_filter( ‘woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html’, ‘con_show_max_variation_price_only’, 10, 2 );
add_filter( ‘woocommerce_variable_price_html’, ‘con_show_max_variation_price_only’, 10, 2 );

function con_show_max_variation_price_only( $price, $product ) {

// Main Variation Price
$prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( ‘max’, true ), $product->get_variation_price( ‘min’, true ) );

$price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( ‘%1$s’, ‘woocommerce’ ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. I tested the code with Envo Multipurpose theme.

```
// define the woocommerce_variable_price_html callback 
function filter_woocommerce_variable_price_html( $wc_format_price_range, $instance ) { 
    $index = strpos($wc_format_price_range, "&ndash; ");
    $wc_format_price_range = substr($wc_format_price_range, $index+7);
    //This will remove the first price by dividing the standard string with dash
    //You may add a prefix like, $wc_format_price_range = "Max Price: $wc_format_price_range";
    return $wc_format_price_range; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'filter_woocommerce_variable_price_html', 10, 2 );
```

I hope this will help you. Have a good day.